# getElementsByClassName not showing data in an element

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are a lot of questions regarding the `getElementsByClassName` not working, however I browsed through many and coudldnt find an answer for my situation.

Basically I have the following code:

```
<script>

var res = localStorage.getItem('img');
    if(res == null){
            const myList = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
            res  = myList[Math.floor(Math.random() * myList.length)];
            localStorage.setItem('img', res);
        }
console.log(res);

document.getElementsByClassName("emoji").innerHTML = res
```

And several spans with same class:

```
<span class="emoji" style="font-size: 40px !important;"></span>
```

The problem is that the "res" doesn't print anything in span.

The console log prints everything fine and LS stores the information perfectly .

I have tried with ID's:

```
document.getElementsById("emoji").innerHTML = res
```

And it works perfectly, however only with the first div (as it should i suppose).

What could I be doing wrong in this situation?

Maybe I am not able to see a very simple mistake in my code.

Comment: You have to put `document.getElementsByClassName("emoji")[0].innerHTML` because `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.emoji').forEach(span => span.textContent = res)`

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `classname` so you have to give index to the class as it puts response only in the first element in the case of id, it is unique but in case of class you have to specify.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("emoji")[0].innerHTML = res;
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple elements can have the same class name. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements that have the class name (it's `Elements` not `Element`). So if you have only 1 element with that class name, you can do `document.getElementsByClassName("emoji")[0].innerHTML = res`.

Answer (score -2):

getElementByClassName always return array of element, usually can read an element from array as index basis, also similar way can get the element  from getElementByClassName.Pls see the below snippet.

```js
const myList = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
var res  = myList[Math.floor(Math.random() * myList.length)];
document.getElementsByClassName("emoji")[0].innerHTML = res
```

```html
<span class="emoji" style="font-size: 40px !important;"></span>
```

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately this only works on the first div with class emoji

Comment: Do you want to print all emoji in different div on same time ?